# One-To-Many relationship in Entity Framework: Why foreign key value is null?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Let's assume each company has some photos (one-to-many relationship).

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int companyID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    // FOREIGN KEY One-To-Many relationship
    public ICollection<Photo> PhotoCollection { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    [Key]
    public int photoID { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
}
```

My database has some records and seems to be correct.

Company table:

```
CompanyID | Name
----------+---------------------
    1     | BestCompany
```

Photo table:

```
PhotoID | Path       | CompanyID (foreign key)
--------+------------+------------------------
    1   | photo1     |      1
    2   | photo2     |      1
```

Getting company to a variable works fine, I can get to it's normal columns (like companyID):

```
var company = await _context.Company
                            .Where(p => p.companyName == "BestCompany")
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Unfortunately, `photos` variable is null:

```
List<Photo>photos = company.PhotoCollection;
```

Why is it null? What am I doing wrong?

I use ASP.NET Core 3 and Entity Framework Core 3.1.1.

Comment: have you tried adding explicit foreign key(companyID) or navigation property (company) on photo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify EF to include child.

```
var company = await _context.Company.Where(p => p.companyName == "BestCompany").Include(p=> p.PhotoCollection).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution fixed it.